# TensorFlow: Batch Norm breaks network when is_training = False

Tags: tensorflow

I am attempting to use a batch norm layer from TensorFlow-Slim as follows:

```
net = ...
net = slim.batch_norm(net, scale = True, is_training = self.isTraining,
    updates_collections = None, decay = 0.9)
net = tf.nn.relu(net)
net = ...
```

I train with:

```
self.optimizer = slim.learning.create_train_op(self.model.loss,
    tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(learning_rate = self.learningRate,
    momentum = 0.9, use_nesterov = True)

optimizer = self.sess.run([self.optimizer],
    feed_dict={self.model.isTraining:True})
```

I load the saved weights with:

```
net = model.Model(sess,width,height,channels,weightDecay)

savedWeightsDir = './savedWeights/'
saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep = 5)
checkpointStr = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(savedWeightsDir)
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
saver.restore(sess, checkpointStr)
global_step = tf.contrib.framework.get_or_create_global_step()
```

and I infer with:

```
inf = self.sess.run([self.softmax],
    feed_dict = {self.imageBatch:imageBatch,self.isTraining:False})
```

Of course I left out a lot and paraphrased some code, but I think this is all that the batch norm touches.  The odd thing is, if I set isTraining:True, I get much better results.  Could it be something with loading in the weights - perhaps the batch norm values are not saved?  Is there anything obviously wrong in the code?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've just run into the same issue and found [solution here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11965).
The problem originates from `tf.layers.batch_normalization` layer which has the need to update **moving_mean** and **moving_variance**.

In order to do that correctly in your case you need to modify your training process as:

```
update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
    self.optimizer = slim.learning.create_train_op(self.model.loss,
      tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(learning_rate = self.learningRate,
      momentum = 0.9, use_nesterov = True)
```

or more generally, from [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/batch_normalization):

```
  x_norm = tf.layers.batch_normalization(x, training=training)

  # ...

  update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
  with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)
```